# Different appearence of typewriter font in algorithm2e procedure

Tags: algorithm2e, typewriter

Let's say we have a procedure in which we want to iterate over an object whose data type we want to specify by writing it in `texttt` font.
I tried

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{procedure}
      \For{$x\in\texttt{myArray}$}{
        $\texttt{MyArray}\gets\texttt{MyArray}.\text{append}(x)$} 
    \caption{MyProcedure()}
\end{procedure}\DecMargin{1em}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the Code]

However, `\texttt{MyArray}` looks different in the for loop and in the body of the loop. How can we make it look like in the body of the loop both times? I already tried to put it outside of math mode, but it did not change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `\mathtt`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{procedure}
      \For{$x\in\mathtt{myArray}$}{
        $\mathtt{MyArray} \gets \mathtt{MyArray}.\text{append}(x)$} 
    \caption{MyProcedure()}
\end{procedure}\DecMargin{1em}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as it is the more elegant one.

Comment: @ItoroJóska It's not only more elegant. It's the most correct.

Answer (score 5):

You could switch to upright font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{procedure}
      \For{$x\in$ \upshape\texttt{myArray}}{
        \texttt{MyArray} $\gets$ \texttt{MyArray}.append(x)} 
    \caption{MyProcedure()}
\end{procedure}\DecMargin{1em}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, it should be `\mathtt`.